# How to stop trail behind moving char in NCurses?

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm making a terminal game in C with the ncurses library.The char @ gets moved around the screen with the WASD keys. However, I want it so that it leaves no trail behind it, as of now it leaves a trail such as @@@@@@@.

Does anyone know a way about this?
Thanks!

Below is the code for moving the char.

```
init_Curses(); //start ncurses
mvwprintw(stdscr, y, x, "@");
curs_set(0);

while (1)
{
     refresh();
     direction = getchar();
     switch (direction)
     {
     //proccess movement with WASD controls
     case 'w':
          y -= 1;
          break;
     case 'a':
          x -= 1;
          break;
     case 's':
          y += 1;
          break;
     case 'd':
          x += 1;
          break;
     default:
          continue;
     }
     if (x == -1 && y == -1)
     {
          y += 1;
          x += 1;
     } //keep in grid
     mvwprintw(stdscr, y, x, "@");
}
endwin();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to delete the trail yourself, ***i.e.*** replace it with the character that was there before `@` *passed*.

You have to keep track of the position were `@` was before and there print the character that was *deleted* by `@`, let's say it was a space:

```
if (x == -1 && y == -1) { y += 1;x += 1;} //keep in grid
    mvwprintw(stdscr,previous_pos_y,previous_pos_x," ");
    mvwprintw(stdscr,y,x,"@");
}
```

Needless to say you must also keep track of such character so you can *restore* it.

Comment: How would you recommend keeping track of the previous char? By appending to some data structure?

Comment: @FiachONeill You could do that, deppending on the complexity of your console, or you can store it in a simple `char` variable, before you move to a given position, store the character in that position beforehand using for instace [mvinch](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcurses/inch.html).

Comment: @FiachONeill `chtype` I mean.